# Can I get all call hierarchy (including caller of caller) by IntellJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to find call hierarchy like following example.

```java
void methodA() {
}

void methodB() {
    methodA();
}

void methodC() {
    methodB();
}

void methodD() {
    methodB();
}
```

I can find following result by using caller hierarchy search to these methods by IDEA.

- methodA by methodB

But I want following tree.

- methodA by methodB

  - methodB by methodC
  - methodB by methodD

Can IntellJ IDEA generate this tree?

Answer (score 0):

When I use [Call Hierarchy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-structure-and-hierarchy-of-the-source-code.html#method) action on `methodA` I get following:

[image]

Isn't it what you have described?

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the function. In my environment, `methodB by methodC` is called via Interface (not by implementation directly).
In that case, calling via interface not shown but all direct calling are shown by Caller method hierarchy.